# Iterating over directory and replacing '+' from a file name to '_' in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory named as assets, which in further has a set of directories.

```
user_images
|-content_images
  |-original
  |-cropped
  |-resize
|-gallery_images
|-slider_images
|-logo
```

These folders can have folders like `original`, `cropped`, `resize`. And these folders further will have images. These images are named something like this – `14562345+Image.jpeg`. I need to replace all the images/files that have `+` to `_`.

```
for f in ls -a;
do
     if [[ $f == ​+​ ]]
       then                
         cp "$f" "${f//+/_}"
       fi
done
```

I was able to do this in the current directory. But I need to iterate this to other many other directories. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this loop using `find` in a process substitution:

```
cd user_images

while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do
   echo "$f"
   mv "$f" "${f//+/_}"
done < <(find . -name '*+*' -type f -print0)
```

Comment: It shows all th files in the directory, but its not renaming the file.

Comment: I meant its not doing anything.

Comment: echo $f shows all the files, but doesn't rename or copy the file.

Comment: This command is full tested and working on my shell. Make sure you're running it with `bash`.  To verify check output of `f='14562345+Image.jpeg'; echo "${f//+/_}"`

Comment: When I individually run this - `mv "$f" "${f//+/_}"`, it works. But when I run with `while`, it doesn't.

Comment: Worked. I guess there were some permission issues.

Answer (score 0):

With `find -exec`:

```
find user_images -type f \
-exec bash -c '[[ $0 == *+* ]] && mv "$0" "${0//+/_}"' {} \;
```

Notice that this uses `mv` and not `cp` as the question states "rename", but simply replace by `cp` if you want to keep the original files.

The `bash -c` is required to be able to manipulate the file names, otherwise we could use `{}` directly in the `-exec` action.

Answer (score 0):

The following will run recursively and will rename all files replacing + with a _ :

```
find . -name '*+*' -type f -execdir bash -c 'for f; do mv "$f" "${f//+/_}"' _ {} +
```

Notice the use of `-execdir` :

> Like  -exec,  but  the specified ***command is run from the subdirectory containing the matched file***, which is not normally the directory in which you started find -- Quoted from `man find`.

Which will protect us in case of directory names matching the pattern `*+*` which you do not want to rename.